# How to get All paths for files in Documents directory?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, nsfilemanager, nsbundle

I usually get paths by using `NSBundle`.

But, `NSBundle` does not contain Documents folder.

How to get All paths(or names) for files in Documents directory?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This will give u the paths for all files under documents directory

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];

    NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);
```

You can get the path for each object in filePathsArray by using the below code

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

To get files from that, you have to give the path structure...

```
    NSString *fileName = @"default.png";
    NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"%@", fileName];
```

The **folderPath** will return you the location of given file name.

Comment: files in Documents directory, not Documents directory.

Comment: Sorry i want know paths or names for all files in doc- dir-, not given file name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is in swift.

Print statement will print all available paths

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
print("Paths - \(paths)")
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```