# Getting an array of items in documents directory iOS

Tags: ios, directory, filepath

I have some folders and subfolders in my documents directory how can i get an array with the files in the directories and subdirectories not the folders just the files.

here is my code so far and it's working if no folders and subfolders exist

```
//getting all the files on documents folder in an array.
    NSError * error;
    NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:documentsDirectory];
NSMutableArray *files = [NSMutableArray array];
BOOL isDirectory;
NSString *path;
while (path = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDirectory] && !isDirectory) {
        [files addObject:path];
    }
}
```

Comment: or change the condition for: `[[enumerator fileAttributes] objectForKey:NSFileType] == NSFileTypeRegular`

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look in older SO link :

1. [How to get All paths for files in Documents directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440662/how-to-get-all-paths-for-files-in-documents-directory)
2. [List saved files in iOS documents directory in a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376511/list-saved-files-in-ios-documents-directory-in-a-uitableview)
3. [Getting a list of files in the Resources folder - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398937/getting-a-list-of-files-in-the-resources-folder-ios)

Comment: yeah i've seen that i want the files only and i'm looking for a recursive way of doing that.

Comment: If you look at 2nd Link : `for (item in contents){
    if ([[item pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) {
        [matches addObject:item];
    }
}` you can always gets path extension for all the files.. with this you can configure your array..