# How to get the local saved UIImage path to UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I am saving my image by using below code ---

```
#define DOCUMENTS_FOLDER [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]


NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
NSString *caldate = [now description];


NSString *filePath= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER,caldate];
imageurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
dataImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myimage);
[dataImage writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

**imageurl is printing like below**

> file://localhost/Users/varmab/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/E2EDF729-4684-465B-8BE3-2C0ACFA2EC03/Documents/2013-03-18%2012:02:31%20+0000.jpg

Now, i want to show the saved image , i.e., image is stored in the above file path

I tried the below codes:

```
//1st process:
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageurl]];

//2nd process:
NSURL *urlString =imageurl;
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlString]])];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

//3rd process:
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageurl ];
self.testingImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
```

Please guide me, am i doing any mistake?

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440662/how-to-get-all-paths-for-files-in-documents-directory

Comment: Use the NSFileManager

Comment: i did like this but, i got null-------  NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"images" ofType:@"jpeg"];
         imgUlr=[NSURL URLWithString:path];
        NSLog(@"********* testingImg is %@",imgUlr); @Rushabh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why dont you directly use this method:

```
 - (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
```

It is already available in `UIImage` class.

```
[self.testingImageView setImage: [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageurl]];
```

Try this, and let me know if you face same issue again.

Note: check the image url whether its similar to the older one, which you are getting while saving that image.

Comment: i am getting, instead of initWithContentsOfURL , i am getting initWithContentsOfFile

Comment: Why I am referring this method, because it will reduce your lines of code. And if you are satisfied with the same then can you please accept and upvote the answer?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the paths for all files under the documents directory;

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];

        NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);
```

You can get the path for each object in filePathsArray by using the below code;

```
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

Get Path of document directory, store image there and from same location, you can retrieve.

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}

if let image = UIImage(named: "example.png") {
    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation() {
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
        try? data.write(to: filename)
    }
}
```