# how to copy Diffrent type of files from document directory in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, directory

i want to copy all type of file that place in document directory to a another directory in ios,

```
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:txtPath] == YES) {
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:txtPath error:&error];
}

NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"txtFile" ofType:@"txt"];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:txtPath error:&error];
```

I M Using This Code But it is only help in specific one type of file.

Comment: Hi this below link can help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440662/how-to-get-all-paths-for-files-in-documents-directory

Comment: Thanx Friend For The Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got My Answer After Doing Some Changes and finding from the other reference and i found this code that running perfect for me

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
filePathsArray1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath  error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code to get all type of files from a directory

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *filePaths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];